# New Site Design - Hard to Read?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, user-interface, formatting

To start, I like the new design in terms of color-themes, fonts (I've always been a fan of Roboto) and usability; it looks fantastic!  That said, the lightness of font-family/low font-weight is making it harder to read questions, to navigate through the list of questions, and especially to read comments because they are a slightly smaller font-size.  I am not sure that I have a great suggestion but here are a couple of ideas:

1. Giving certain things (Comments, Questions-List, Question-Page text) a heavier font-weight/larger font-size or possibly a different color that would stand out more.
2. Utilizing background colors to make the existing text stand out a little more
3. Reverting to the previous font or using `Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;` like Stack Overflow does.

I don't know if this is the correct forum to start a discussion about this (or if there even is one), and I am certainly not saying anything negative about the new design in general, but I am sure that we can all agree which of the following two screen-snips is easier to read:

**Magento Stack Exchange:**
[image: Magento Stack Exchange Question and Comment]

**Stack Overflow:**
[image: Stack Overflow Question and Comments]

Comment: are u  from stackexchanges?

Comment: @AmitBera - If you mean do I represent Stack Exchange, No.  I am not affiliated outside of my activity within the Stack Exchange/Overflow communities.

Answer (score 2):

I see magento.stackexchange.com as below

[image]

As you can see, the font seems good and which is not look like what you shared in your question. The font used here as per the browser console is `Roboto, Arial, sans-serif`. The font is same in both Mozilla and Chrome.

Also if you see the `primary.css` file which is used by this site, you can see this definition

```
html,body {
    color: #3D4245;
    font-family: 'Roboto',Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.30769231
}
```

And most of the elements are inheriting this style. Example: `<p></p>`

So there may be something went wrong on your side, maybe. I cannot point out what exactly went wrong here since I am not a CSS expert.

Side note: StackOverflow seems to use `Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  I typically use Chrome, but I have viewed some pages in Firefox that look the same way that you posted.  I am guessing that Chrome is using `Roboto`, which I have installed in my system fonts, and Firefox is using the fallback `Arial` which looks the same as StackOverflow, despite the different font-family assignments.  As you pointed out, this won't be affecting everyone, but I am sure I am not the only one who has Roboto installed.